# How to make following jquery code more efficient

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jsp

I have a table in a jsp page containing only one input field in each row for user input. The requirement is to keep the submit button disabled if even one of the textfield is empty and enable it only when all are filled. I have given the input field classname "QtytobePacked".

It is working fine for 100 or so rows, but for when row number is increased to greater than 500, say 1200, it becomes very slow. Is there any faster way to do so?

```
$('body').bind("change keyup mousemove", function(event) {

    var isValid = true;
    $('.QtytobePacked').each(function() {

        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            isValid = false;
            document.getElementById('symbol icon-error').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById('myPopup').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById('myPopup3').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('myPopup4').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            $('#save_button').prop("disabled", true);
            $('#save_button').attr('class', 'upload_button_inactive');

        }
    });

    if (isValid) {
        //alert(isValid);
        document.getElementById('myPopup').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('myPopup3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('myPopup4').style.visibility = 'visible';
        $('#save_button').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#save_button').attr('class', 'upload_button_active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Try to keep your `document.getElementById()` outside bind function and store it in variable. Also you can try to keep jquery elements in variables too.

Comment: Why don't you just check for each field if it has input and set the button with an if-else statement. As soon as you find a field with length 0 (.val() == '') you break.:

.each(function(){if$(this).val() == ''){isValid = false; break;}} if(isValid){submitButton.setVisible()}else{submitButton.setInvisible()}}

Cut the code and paste it somewhere you can properly format it..

Comment: Another way would be to add an "oninputListener" to each input. Then the function that is called checks if the length is > 0. For each input you could store a boolean array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion the code inside

> if ($(this).val() === '') {...}

is quite heavy if called again and again..

my suggestion is to break the iteration when you meet the first "textfield is empty" so you will only run this codes once, using `return true`

> isValid = false;
>               document.getElementById('myPopup').style.visibility = 'hidden';
>               document.getElementById('myPopup3').style.visibility = 'visible';
>               document.getElementById('myPopup4').style.visibility = 'hidden';
>               $('#save_button').prop("disabled", true);
>               $('#save_button').attr('class', 'upload_button_inactive');

hoppefuly my snippet bellow will help improve your js process time.

have a nice day!

```js
$('body').bind("change keyup mousemove", function(event) {

    var isValid = true;
    $('.QtytobePacked').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            isValid = false;
            document.getElementById('myPopup').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById('myPopup3').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('myPopup4').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            $('#save_button').prop("disabled", true);
            $('#save_button').attr('class', 'upload_button_inactive');
            
            // stop the iteration, so the code at line 8 will only run once per iteration.
            return true
        }
    });

    if (isValid) {
        //alert(isValid);
        document.getElementById('myPopup').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('myPopup3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('myPopup4').style.visibility = 'visible';
        $('#save_button').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#save_button').attr('class', 'upload_button_active');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myPopup">myPopup</div>
<div id="myPopup3">myPopup3</div>
<div id="myPopup4">myPopup4</div>

<input type="button" id ="save_button" value="save">

<!-- this will be validated-->
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">

<!-- stop validate after this input-->
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="">

<!-- not need to validate-->
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
<input type="text" class="QtytobePacked" value="hahahaha">
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to achieve performance is to use jQuery [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function and [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/). Also you should define all variables outside the loop. These changes should create a significant performance speed up.Try to test this:

```
$(function() {

  const $symbol = $('#symbol icon-error');
  const $myPopup = $('#myPopup');
  const $myPopup3 = $('#myPopup3');
  const $myPopup4 = $('#myPopup4');
  const $saveBtn = $('#save_button');

  $('body').on("change keyup mousemove", function(event) {

    var isValid;

    $('.QtytobePacked').each(function() {
      isValid = $(this).val() !== '';

      $symbol.toggle(isValid);
      $myPopup.toggle(!isValid);
      $myPopup3.toggle(!isValid);
      $myPopup4.toggle(!isValid);

      $saveBtn.prop('disabled', !isValid).toggleClass('upload_button_active upload_button_inactive');
    });
  })
});
```